# Insert new values into an array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, insert, vectorization

I currently have a column vectors of different lengths and I want to insert another column vector at various points of the original array. i.e. I want to add my new array to the start of the old array skip 10 places add my new array again, skip another 10 spaces and add my new array again and so on till the end of the array. I can do this by using:

```
OffsetSign = [1:30]';
Extra = [0;0;0;0;0];
OffsetSign =[Extra;OffsetSign(1:10);Extra;OffsetSign(11:20);Extra;OffsetSign(21:30)];
```

However this is not suitable for longer arrays. Any tips on an easy way to do this for longer arrays?

Answer (score 4):

here's one way to do it:

```
a = [1:30]';
b = [0;0;0;0;0];

a=reshape(a,10,[]);
b=repmat(b,[1 size(a,2)])
r=[b ; a]
r=r(:);
```

the trick is to reshape `a` to a matrix with columns of the right size (10 elements each). Replicate `b` to this # of columns , concatenate both and flatten the matrix to a vector...

Comment: As a side, not-too-serious note: isn't a matrix already flat? Shouldn't we say (for lack of a better word) "_threaden_ to a vector"? Or which would be the right word?

Comment: Would never have thought of that! Your a genius! Thanks

Comment: @LuisMendo: how about "linearize"? Because that's the form in which linear indexing and regular indexing are the same.

Comment: though I like it, it also has the meaning of finding the linear approximation to a function at a given point...