# How to find the maximum of multiple arrays in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, max

Let's say we have an array `x`. We can find the maximum value of this array as follows:

```
maximum = max(x);
```

If I have two arrays, let's say x and y, I can find the array that contains the maximum value by using the command

```
maximum_array = max(x, y);
```

Let's say that this array is y. Then, I can find the maximum value by using the max command with argument y, as before with x:

```
maximum_value = max(y);
```

This two-step procedure could be performed with the following compact, one-liner command:

```
maximum_value = max(max(x, y));
```

But what happens when we have more than 2 arrays? As far as I know, the max function does not allow to compare more than two arrays. Therefore, I have to use max for pairs of arrays, and then find the max among the intermediate results (which involves also the use of additional variables). Of course, if I have, let's say, 50 arrays, this would be - and it really is - a tedius process.

Is there a more efficient approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Approach #1**

Concatenate `column` vector versions of them along `dim-2` with **[`cat`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cat.html)** and then use maximium values with **[`max`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/max.html)** along `dim-2` to get the max.

Thus, assuming `x`, `y` and `z` to be the input arrays, do something like this -

```
%// Reshape all arrays to column vectors with (:) and then use cat
M = cat(2,x(:),y(:),z(:))

%// Use max along dim-2 with `max(..,[],2)` to get column vector 
%// version and then reshape back to the shape of input arrays
max_array = reshape(max(M,[],2),size(x))
```

---

**Approach #2**

You can use **[`ndims`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndims.html)** to find the number of dimensions in the input arrays and then concatenate along the dimension that is `plus 1` of that dimension and finally find `max` along it to get the maximum values array. This would avoid all of that reshaping back and forth and thus could be more efficient and a more compact code as well -

```
ndimsp1 = ndims(x)+1                         %// no. of dimensions plus 1
maxarr = max(cat(ndimsp1,x,y,z),[],ndimsp1)  %// concatenate and find max
```

Comment: Thank you! The "columnization" ( :-) ) of the arrays makes perfect sense to begin with, I should have thought of that...

Comment: @Kotsos Except that it's not a smiley!

Comment: Yeah, it just seems to me a funny word - I don't know if it is even valid English or not!

Comment: @Kotsos I think that's a fair enough word for it!!

Comment: @Kotsos We often say "linearization", because the array is transformed into linear shape (i.e. only one dimension)

Comment: @LuisMendo Ah yes, that's the magic word for it! Thanks for reminding/telling us!

Comment: @LuisMendo Thanks! I improved both my coding and English skills with this post. Who could tell!

Comment: Credit for that word [goes to A. Donda](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19408989/2586922), as far as I can tell  @Kotsos Divakar

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest approach for a small set of arrays is to column-ify and concatenate:

```
maxValue = max([x(:);y(:)]);
```

For a large number of arrays in some data structure (e.g. a cell array or a struct), I simple loop would be best:

```
maxValue = max(cellOfMats{1}(:));
for k = 2:length(cellOfMats)
    maxValue = max([maxValue;cellOfMats{k}(:)]);
end
```

For the pathological case of a large number of separate arrays with differing names, I say "don't do that" and put them in a data structure or use `eval` with a loop.